# Best Way to generate a list of three unique numbers between 0 and 9

Tags: c#, random, while-loop

It is all in the title basically. It is simple, but I don't know why my While loop is failing sometimes. Every now and then I would get a list that is of length 2 instead of 3.

Here is my C# code:

```
public List<int> generateRequiredSecretCode()
{
    List<int> placeHolder = new List<int>();
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNo = random.Next(0, 10);
    while (!placeHolder.Contains(randomNo) && placeHolder.Count != 3)
    {
        placeHolder.Add(randomNo);
        randomNo = random.Next(0, 10);
    }
    return placeHolder;
}
```

Summary of my aim: I want a *List of integers* that is of **length 3** and where each number in the list is between 0 and 9 and is **unique**

Comment: Sorry, I just have to.. can't resist: `return new List {0,1,2};`. Sorry again, my bad. You want random number, I know. =)

Comment: If that is your only criteria why use a random number generate. Doesn't `{1,2,3}` meet all 3 requirements?

Comment: I've run this in linqpad - I sometimes get 1 entry.

Comment: @Jens That sure is [random](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!placeHolder.Contains(randomNo)` is your problem here because the while ends if the list contains the randomNo.
Check that `!placeHolder.Contains(randomNo)` in an inner if like this:

```
while (placeHolder.Count != 3)
{
    if( !placeHolder.Contains(randomNo) )
      placeHolder.Add(randomNo);
    randomNo = random.Next(0, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can have a neat LINQ two-liner using

```
var random = new Random();
return Enumerable.Range(0,10).OrderBy(i => random.NextDouble()).Take(3).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a really pretty solution. I didn't know that it would supply distinct numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes fails because, in the rare cases when Rand.Next does return an identical number to thise already in the list, `!placeHolder.Contains(randomNo)` will return false; false && anything = false, so the loop ends. If you'd run it long enough, you'd eventually get a list of length 1 ;)

Possible replacement:

```
List<int> placeHolder = new List<int>();
Random random = new Random();
int randomNo;
do {
    randomNo = random.Next(0, 10);
    if (!placeHolder.Contains(randomNo) && placeHolder.Count != 3)
    {
         placeHolder.Add(randomNo);
         randomNo = random.Next(0, 10);
    }
} while (placeHolder.Count < 3);
return placeHolder;
```

[edit]: This thread moved fast... and Animal's solution is much better than mine :(

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but set arithmetic seems quite elegant so couldn't resist:

```
private static Random RNG = new Random();

...

public static List<int> RandomNumbers() {
  var numbers = new HashSet<int> { RNG.Next(0, 9), RNG.Next(0, 9), RNG.Next(0, 9) };
  while (numbers.Count < 3) 
  {
    numbers.Add(RNG.Next(0, 9));
  }

  return numbers.ToList();
}
```